Flutter app crashing on launch and stuck on gradelBuild
This has never happened in any of my previous flutter projects, but when i try and run my app in an emulator, the app pops up and then crashes without any error message and continues building the app without anything happening.


I did some tests and noticed that it starts happening when I add the "buildscript{}" in the build.gradle file in the android directory:
buildscript {     ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'     repositories {         google()         mavenCentral()     }      dependencies {         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'         // START: FlutterFire Configuration         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2' // Required for Firebase         // END: FlutterFire Configuration         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"     } }  allprojects {     repositories {         google()         mavenCentral()     } }  rootProject.buildDir = '../build' subprojects {     project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}" } subprojects {     project.evaluationDependsOn(':app') } tasks.register("clean", Delete) {     delete rootProject.buildDir }
Sometimes I get an error saying that the kotlin version doens't match the binary version.
I have the latest version of flutter and have already tried "flutter pub upgrade", "flutter clean", all of that.
This is my flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows
    [Version 10.0.22631.4317], locale pt-PT)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10
    or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
    version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"` 
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for 
      more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK 
      licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for more 
      details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio
    Community 2022 17.8.3)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please     
      re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop       
      development with C++" workload, and include these
      components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, 
         install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources



Run flutter doctor --android-licenses on cmd and accept the licenses.
Navigate to the following and select this box

Issue 2 Reference link

